# DVI-D (Dual Link) to VGA Adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, display-adapter

I have just both a DVI-D (Male) to VGA (Female) Adapter so I use dual monitors when using my computer. I have an ECS H61H2-M2 Motherboard with an I3-2120 CPU with no graphics card installed (out of budget). But anyways, I've tried two adapters and both of these adapters doesn't work. I curious and a little bit frustrated because up to now I can't still use both of my LCD monitors on my desktop. I've done checking both LCDs if there both working and they are when I've tried switching both on the VGA port available on the motherboard

My question is if any case there's a problem on the following how can I troubleshoot it:

- Adapter
- DVI-D (Female) Slot

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVI-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvi) ports are "digital only" and do not provide an analog (VGA) signal to work with your **DVI-I to VGA** adapter. You need either a monitor with a DVI-D port, or a motherboard or video adapter with DVI-I output.